# Strange language settings in Excel Online

Tags: excel-online

I've a personal Office account, and using Excel Online I've realized that the language of OneDrive and Excel is English, and I see everything in English, except formulas.

When I type formulas I get the suggestions in Hungarian, and also see entered formulas in Hungarian. When I select functions, I see the list in English, however help is in Hungarian (see "SZÖVEGÖSSZEFŰZÉS" at the bottom of the picture), and inserting the function inserts it in Hungarian:

[image: Help in Hungarian]

The issue is the same with both Google Chrome 56.0.2924.87 and Internet Explorer 11 (both from the same PC with Windows 7, if that matters).

How can I fix this?